# Rails add column with default value with no affect on current entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I use rails 4 with postgreSQL 
I want to add a new column with default value

```
add_column :users, :first_visit, :boolean, :default => true
```

and have all new entries created with value true but need to have all the current entries not to be affected by default value but have a nil value on first_visit field.

Comment: Default means it will set for all the entries. I don't think it will be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:default => true` in migration add `true` for all existing records.

If you want `nil` for existing records and `true` default value then remove `:default => true` from migration and add below code in user model:

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_create :set_default

    def set_default
        self.first_visit = true unless self.first_visit
    end
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the only way to achieve this purely within the database is to set the default value in PostgreSQL using the command you quote, and then run a global update to set all the current values to null.

```
User.update_all(first_visit: nil)
```